# ASP.net: Code explanation of delegates and events

Tags: asp.net-2.0

Given this code:

```
WriteThisMessageToThePage1.sendMessageToThePage += delegate(string message)
```

Can anyone explain me what this line means in delagates? What does this code represent?

Answer (score 0):

+= is a short hand notation for subscribing to an event. The `delegate(string message)` code represents the event handler for the event. In this case the event handler is an anonymous method. When the sendMessageToThePage event fires, the code next += is executed.